# get configurable swatches in homepage product list (Custom product list)

Tags: magento-1.9, swatches, color-swatches

I have populated bestselling products on homepage. It's populating list of products as desired. Now i have enabled `configurable swatches` & have enabled on product listing(i'm using rwd theme).

I can see color swatches on product lists in my product listing page. Now i want those swatches on my custom product list at homepagepage.

What i tried:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('configurableswatches/catalog/product/list/swatches.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

This above prints nothing.

And i get all the code from `rwd/default/theme/configurableswatches/catalog/product/list/swatches.phtml` inside products populating loop. And it worked and shows the swatches, but now clicking on swatches has no effect to image ? (Image doesn't changes as like it does on product listing for same product even after i added all configurableswatches js under `skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/configurableswatches/*.js`).

What is the best way to achieve configurable swatches on custom product list on homepage ?

Answer (score 0):

To show configurable swatch on Home Page in Feature Products List, follow the below steps -

1- Make your own list.phtml file for custom products list
2- in your list.phtml file select place where you want to show configurable swatches, and paste below code -

```
$_nameAfterChild = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list.swatches');
$_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
```

3- Include this file in Home Page in CMS using below code -

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="5" category_id="21" template="catalog/product/homepage-list.phtml"}}
```

4- In local.xml file in your theme paste below code -

```
    <cms_index_index>
         <update handle="product_list"/>
    </cms_index_index>
```